# Shopware 5 Extension Problem with OneTo Many Association

Tags: shopware

I try to code a plugin for the Shopware 5 Environment.

The plugin should be able to do the following:
Create customer advisors with name and email (this part works actually pretty well)

In a second Backend App you should now be able to create customer relationships.
This Detailview has two Comoboxes.
So from first Combobox you should be able to select a companyname and the corresponding customer ID should be saved.
In a second combo box you should now be able to select one of the previously created customer advisors. (This part works as well)

My Problem is: That I don't have any idea why my combobox which should hold the company names is empty.
I realy don't have any idea.

[I used this tutorial as a guide:](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/backend-components/associations/)

[Here is the link to my gitrepo:](https://github.com/juliansunten/shopware-customer-assistant)